# Navigating MasterPage From LoginPage Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, master-pages

I am currently working on Xamarin forms and I got stuck trying to open MasterPage after a user presses the login button. 
Thanks in advance.

```
    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Tried this way with errors
        Navigation.PushAsync(new MasterDetailPage());
        //And tried this one too with erros
        Navigation.PushModelAsync(new MasterDetailPage());

    }
```

Comment: What are the specific "errors" you get?  MasterDetail generally needs to be the root page, you can't contain it within a NavigationPage.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(loginSuccess)
{
App.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();
}
else
{
DisplayAlert("Error", "unable to login", "OK");
}
```

try this.here MainPage is MasterDetailPage.

Comment: Thanks. I needed that too. I forgot to make the page root MasterDetailPage. But I used a similar style of validating the user login first.

Answer (score 2):

set **MasterDetailPage** as a root page and if user not logged in then Navigation.PushModalAsync(new LoginPage()) and on login button Navigation.PopAsync()